# Change IP address, subnet mask, dns servers and default gateway in C#

Tags: c#, networking, dns, ip, gateway

I am VERY new to C#.  I want to create a small console app that sets the following:

```
IP address: 192.168.10.133
Subnet mask: 255.255.255.0
Default gateway: 192.168.10.66
Preferred DNS server: 192.168.10.3
Alternate DNS server: 192.168.10.5
```

and another small app that clears that information and sets `"Obtain an IP address automatically"` and `"Obtain DNS server address automatically"`.

I've found some examples of scripts that people have posted on this forum and other forums, but I can't get them to work.

It might be a lot to ask, but I would appreciate if someone could post something here that will help me.

I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have decided to go another route with this.  Instead of using C#, I'm simply going to set it via a batch file.

set_static_ip.bat

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1
netsh interface ip set dnsservers "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.3 primary
```

The first line sets the ip and default gateway.
The second line sets the primary dns server.  I haven't been able to set the alternate dns, but i'm sure i'm just missing something.

If you want to change the configuration back to obtain an ip address automatically, then you simply run the code below.

set_auto_ip.bat

```
netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" source="dhcp"
netsh interface ip set dnsservers name="Local Area Connection" source=dhcp
```

Simple yet effective.

Answer (score 2):

You can use WMI(Windows management instrumentation) to achieve this

Here is an extremely  good tutorial to start with.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5697/Configuring-TCP-IP-Settings-using-WMI-and-C

Answer (score 0):

Just to add one additional point to narfie's very helpful post (on Sep 12 '14 at 13:01).

If you want to set the alternate DNS address along with the primary one, use the following:

> netsh interface ip set address name="Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1
>
> netsh interface ip set dnsservers "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.3 primary
>
> netsh interface ipv4 add dns name="Local Area Connection" 196.14.239.2

Answer (score 0):

Check this app. It can set IPs for both ethernet and wifi with single button click. It can set predefined static or dhcp config

https://github.com/kamran7679/ConfigureIP.git

Answer (score -4):

Change TCP/IP settings

TCP/IP defines the language that your computer uses to communicate with other computers. We recommend using automated Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol (DHCP) to automatically assign Internet Protocol (IP) addresses to the computers on your network, if your network supports it. If you use DHCP, then you don't have to change your settings if you move your computer to another location, and DHCP doesn't require you to manually configure settings such as Domain Name System (DNS) and Windows Internet Name Service (WINS).

1.

```
  Open Network Connections by clicking the Start button Picture of the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Network and Internet, clicking Network and Sharing Center, and then clicking Manage network connections.
```

2.

```
  Right-click the connection that you want to change, and then click Properties. Administrator permission required If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or provide confirmation.
```

3.

```
  Click the Networking tab. Under This connection uses the following items, click either Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) or Internet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/IPv6), and then click Properties.
```

4.

```
  To specify IPv4 IP address settings, do one of the following:
      *

        To obtain IP settings automatically, click Obtain an IP address automatically, and then click OK.
      *

        To specify an IP address, click Use the following IP address, and then, in the IP address, Subnet mask, and Default gateway boxes, type the IP address settings.
```

5.

```
  To specify IPv6 IP address settings, do one of the following:
      *

        To obtain IP settings automatically, click Obtain an IPv6 address automatically, and then click OK.
      *

        To specify an IP address, click Use the following IPv6 address, and then, in the IPv6 address, Subnet prefix length, and Default gateway boxes, type the IP address settings.
```

6.

```
  To specify DNS server address settings, do one of the following:
      *

        To obtain a DNS server address automatically, click Obtain DNS server address automatically, and then click OK.
      *

        To specify a DNS server address, click Use the following DNS server addresses, and then, in the Preferred DNS server and Alternate DNS server boxes, type the addresses of the primary and secondary DNS servers.
```

7.

```
  To change DNS, WINS, and IP settings, click Advanced.
```